# Show that Y is a pivotal quantity

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, scale-invariance, invariance, pivot

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ denote a random sample from $Unif(0,\theta)$. Find a function of the MLE for $\theta$ that is a pivotal quantity.

I have the sampling distribution of $X_n$, $f_{x_n}(x)=n[\frac{x}{\theta}]^{(n-1)}\times \frac{1}{\theta}$

Let $Y=\frac{X_n^{n-1}}{\theta^{n-1}}$

Show that the density of Y does not depend on $\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

let $X_{(n)}=\max\left(X_1,\cdots, X_n \right)$

$$f_{X_{(n)}}(x)=n(\frac{x}{\theta})^{n-1} \frac{1}{\theta}$$

so CDF is
$$F_{X_{(n)}}(x)=(\frac{x}{\theta})^{n}$$

$$\left(\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}\right)^{n}\sim Uniform(0,1)$$